# SQL query crashed site or not responding from SQL to execute query

Tags: sql-server

I have 5000 record into my database. Now I am going to update 500 record at a time but my site going to crash due to this execution and also SQL server not responding. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
public void UpdateProductStatus(int[] productIds)
{
  if (productIds == null || productIds.Count() == 0)
  return;

  _dbContext.ExecuteSqlCommand(
      " DECLARE @TempPIds AS TABLE(Id INT) " +
      " INSERT INTO @TempPIds" +
      " SELECT * FROM  dbo.Split('" + string.Join(",", productIds) + "', ',') OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) " +
      " UPDATE Product SET IndexStatus = 1" +
      " FROM Product p INNER JOIN @TempPIds tp ON p.Id = tp.Id WHERE IndexStatus = 0");
}


ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Delimiter NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    WITH Split(stpos,endpos)
    AS(
        SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
            FROM Split
            WHERE endpos > 0
    )
    SELECT --'Id' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
        'Data' = SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)
    FROM Split
)
```

This query is proper but its slow down my site as well as SQL server. Please can anyone help me to speed up this query or alternative way to update my indexstatus?

Comment: There's no `dbo.Split` function in SQL Server. That's a custom function. We can't guess why it crashes. Post your code. BTW there's no recursion involved in this query

Comment: Add the code for tables (with indexes) and your `Split` function. Declare a primary key on `@TempPIds(Id)`. It would be better to pass a table-valued parameter than splitting a string.

Comment: Is there a purpose to joining the items and then splitting them?

Comment: BTW why *join* and *split* when you use dynamic sql? You get all of the SQL injection risks and none of the dynamic sql benefits. You can replace the entire script with `UPDATE ..... FROM Product p where ID in ('+ string.Join(...) +') and IndexStatus=0`

Comment: Splitting would only make sense if you passed the ID list as a paremeter, eg `@ids`. Instead of using a temporary table, you could just join with the results of dbo.Split, eg `UPDATE ... FROM Product p INNER JOIN dbo.Split(@ids) ids on ids.Item=p.ID where IndexStatus=0`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos your solution thow me maxrecusion error

Comment: @AndrewMorton i have productids now how to update this product record using only ids? do you have any another solution for this?

Comment: @SangeetShah no it doesn't. It's `dbo.Split` that does, because it uses a slow method of string splitting that's known to fail for long strings. If you google for `T-SQL STRING SPLIT` you'll see that the fastest method uses XML. You don't need this either though, just put the ID string in an `IN` clause.

Comment: BTW all SQL Server versions still in mainstream support (ie 2016 and later) have `STRING_SPLIT`

Comment: @SangeetShah for older versions, *all* string splitting functions use one of the techniques [described in Aaron Bertrand's articles](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings). The fastest method is a SQLCLR method. Notice that the CTE version is very different from your own

Comment: Also note the last paragraph - you can get rid of splitting entirely if you use a table-valued parameter. Performance will be worse than dynamic SQL with an `IN` clause because the server can't calculate statistics for the TVP but then, it can't do that for `Split` either. The TVP will be *faster* than splitting though

Answer (score 0):

put the ID string in an IN clause without split Could be wrong
Because a number can be contained within a number, if ID 12 is updated 12,1,2.

And for the TVP you can transfer to a temporary table and then you also gain performance